# How can I do HTTPS redirection on IIS?

Tags: redirect, iis

I have a website called [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and I host it on google sites. The NS and Hosting part of my old website called [www.example.org](http://www.example.org) is hosted on a windows server of my own. The hosting part is running on IIS 6.2. I redirected this [www.example.org](http://www.example.org) website to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) via IIS. I did not have any problems with redirection.

When I enter the address bar in this way, I can access it directly. However, since the indexing on the google side is done as https, no link clicked on google does not work. My [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) site opens as https on google sites, but redirection is not active on links coming with https via [www.example.org](http://www.example.org). Only redirects coming with http are active. Whatever I did, I could not find a solution to this problem. Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Open applicationHost.config file and show us the settings you used to configure redirection.

Comment: Your redirects should be affected by your rewrite rule, not Google, how did you configure your redirects?